# MongoDB will not uninstall

Tags: init.d, uninstall, mongodb

So, it would appear that following the official MongoDB installation instructions when installing on Debian - you're heading for a world of pain. Firstly, it didn't install correctly so now - i'm trying to remove all installed MongoDB packages so that I can start from scratch.

Frustratingly, because it didn't install cleanly (presumably), it won't uninstall.

Originally, I installed using the instructions here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/

Currently, i've managed to remove every package apart from ***mongodb-org-server*** which, just won't go.

An attempted removal results in the following:

```
user@host:/$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb-org-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 23.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 31030 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongod not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongod not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is causing me untold problems, any ideas how I can properly and cleanly get rid of MongoDB now?

Contents of **/var/lib/dpkg/info/mongodb-org-server.prerm**:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -e "/etc/init/mongod.conf" ]; then
        invoke-rc.d mongod stop || exit $?
fi
# End automatically added section
```

Jordan

Comment: This is probably best done interactively (based on past experience). Care to hop into the chat room? You can ping me from there. Though, actually, a simple workaround might be to create an empty `/etc/init.d/mongod`. Try that first.

Comment: Also, post the prerm script for `mongodb-org-server`, namely `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mongodb-org-server.prerm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mongodb-org-server` package appears to be broken. 
The prerm script `mongodb-org-server.prerm` is trying to run the script
`/etc/init.d/mongod` as part of `invoke-rc.d`. As the name suggests, the `prerm` script is run by `dpkg` prior to removal of the `mongodb-org-server` package.

The poster said the server was not running, so the prerm script is therefore a no-op.

So, the obvious thing to do is to comment out the relevant part of `mongodb-org-server.prerm`, namely:

```
if [ -e "/etc/init/mongod.conf" ]; then
        invoke-rc.d mongod stop || exit $?
fi
```

and then run the removal again. Though I would recommend

```
apt-get purge mongodb-org-server
```

and report a bug against this package if possible.

Comment: Thanks Faheem; this has now been raised with MongoDB as a bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17420, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14786